# Convert for loop to lambda/list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, loops, lambda, list-comprehension

I have a list, loc_combinations, with a length of 91806 of unique ID pairs structured as so:

```
[(1,2), (1,3), 1,4)...(452, 454)]
```

I am trying to apply the same function `distance_calculator` to each pair in the list which returns a single value, the distance. I was able to get my answer using a for loop but was hoping someone could show me how to do it using Lambda and list comprehension.

**Here is the for loop:**

```
distance_list = []
for i in range(len(loc_combinations)): 
    distance_list.append(distance_calculator(id1 = loc_combinations[i][0], id2 = loc_combinations[i][1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for a lambda function if you have a working function defined. Your code as a list comprehension looks like this:

```
distance list = [distance_calculator(x[0], x[1]) for x in loc_combinations]
```

Comment: or `distance_calculator(*x)` if you're nasty

Answer (score 0):

```py
distance_list = [
    distance_calculator(id1=x, id2=y)
    for x, y in loc_combinations
]
```